# supressing link_to default action in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I read on this part of the ruby guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

that it is not always ideal to cram things into CRUD.  I have a case for this, I want to have a final "submit" button after a survey that goes through and re validates that all data has indeed been filled out (since you can work on the survey in parts and it will save and validate to the database) but for final submission EVERYTHING has to be filled out.  So my submit link_to I would like to call a method in the controller:

in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Submit", :action => 'final_verify', :document_id => @document.id  %>
```

now I am using wicked as a wizard controller, sO i had to create a route to match so this call would work:

routes.rb:

```
  #match route so I can call from page_controller.rb
  match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

So this works, it runs etc, but the issue is then if there is an error in the final_verify I want to redirect to a specific page, do I create a route for this?   or do I have to just finagle the redirect_to to do this properly?  I cannot seem to figure out the best/correct way to do this?

I am not convinced my matched route is even the right way to go just to get the link_to to call that final verify and goto the offending page (if any) so users can complete required parts and try submitting again.  (Partially whats tripping me up is how to do this using the wicked gem https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Answer (score 0):

The route you created is actually a legacy, "wild controller" route (only action and id is not optional), that would match on any controller, action and id. If you're doing a RESTful app, that's not recommended.

It would be better if you created a named route for your specific purpose:

```
match 'submit/:document_id' => 'your_controller#final_verify', :as => :final_verify
```

The first part is the url that will be available, the middle part is the controller and action that should be called, and the third part is the route name, that will give you the `final_verify_path` and `final_verify_url` methods in your views and controllers. So your link_to call would look like this:

```
<%= link_to "Submit", final_verify_path(:document_id => @document.id)  %>
```

And to show an error after submitting an incomplete survey, you basically have 2 options:

- render a template as a result of your action
- redirect to a different action

Seems like you want to do the second, so you need to `redirect_to` an action in a controller which would display the errors, for example on the correct wizard page. If you leave your legacy route as is, you probably don't have to do anything else. But if you choose to use named routes, you'll just have to define another route and use it in the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The 'submit/:document_id' what is that?  I tried that verbatim and get the error:  `uninitialized constant Document::Page`

Comment: This is the path - "submit" is a constant part (can be "survey" or whatever you want) - it's just an example. The ":document_id" is the parameter, so the real url will be for example http://yourdomain.com/submit/146
You copied the whole line verbatim, or changed your_controler to a real controller name?

Comment: Verbatim might of been poor choice of words.  My controller where the final_verify method (action) is in is page_controller.rb which lives under:  controllers/document/page_controller.rb